# Correct way to multiply Bayesian interacting terms with Cred Intervals

Tags: r, jags

So I've built a (long computational time) jags mixed model that includes an interaction term in the fixed effects. After the fact I want to multiply two of the posterior means for the regression coefficients - with credible intervals.

Example:

```
library(lme4)
library(runjags)

model <- template.jags(total.fruits ~ reg + amd*gen + (1 | reg), data=Arabidopsis, family = "poisson")

# can ignore warning for this demo

ml.jags <- run.jags(model)
summary(ml.jags)
```

So I want to work out the value of amd*gen for level 2 of amd afterwards. # For the Mean or Median I can multiply the terms

```
> results[row.names(results) == "amd_effect[2]", "Mean"] * results[row.names(results) == "gen_coefficient_amd_level[2]", "Mean"]
[1] 0.0001745244
```

But how do I put credible intervals around this since multiplying the credible intervals directly is wrong? I know in a frequentist framework I can do this using the standard errors but I was not sure if that is true also in Bayesian stats?

Comment: Normally when I see interaction models they would be of the form total.fruits ~ reg + amd + gen + amd*gen.... Is there a reason you didn't go this route? Also can you provide a bit more detail about what you're trying to do? I'm not sure I follow, but normally you work with the entire set of posterior samples and then calculate your quantiles of interest directly (e.g. 0.025, 0.5, 97.5).

Comment: The notation `amd*gen` in this model implies: `amd + gen + amd:gen` allowing for main effects of both terms and interaction term. I no longer have the posterior samples only the summary data. I didn't anticipate wanting to do this you see and they were taking up mountains of disk space.

Comment: Also just as an aside, I would highly recommend you switch to rstanarm. Uses lme4 syntax but is being kept to date by some premier applied Bayesians. I only use JAGS when I have to adapt someone's JAGS code by hand.

Comment: Ah OK. Well if you have the posterior standard deviation still and are willing to assuming your posterior was normally distributed than you could use that in place of standard error in whatever calculations you would normally do. It's not strictly correct though.

Comment: Yeah learning STAN is in my list of things to do. If they release within thread parallelisation via MPI I'll be all over it :) Ok thanks I might do that as a temporary solution.....it will take weeks to rerun everything and I'll have gone insane before then!

Answer (score 1):

Error propagation of this sort is easy in MCMC-based Bayesian statistics.  Instead of multiplying summary statistics of the posterior (like the means or medians), multiply the ACTUAL MCMC samples from the posterior chains.  Since each iteration of the chain is a valid sample from the joint posterior distribution, you can do the multiplication at each iteration of the chain to get a new chain that represents samples from the posterior distribution of the derived parameter.  Then, simply conduct your inference on this new chain (e.g. find the median, mode, credible interval, or whatever feature of the posterior you are interested in).